# One Question, 2 right answers, who gets the tick in the box?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

As the titles states, I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137031/ubuntu-tweak-updates-every-day-is-this-correct/137043#comment163383_137043) and 2 people gave the correct answer at the same time.  Answer 1 was originally incorrect but he put effort in and eventually came to the same conclusion as answer 2 through commenting.  My instinct tells me to give the tick the Answer 2 which was right first time.  What would you do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which one shows more research, effort, explanations and is a general, better all-around answer? Pick that one.

Comment: I guess they both did but I made my choice.  I do have a conscience LoL Thanks